# Google appscript - if else statement not working in for loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

Trying to run the else statement in below code but cant make it work.
What am i missing here?

```
var startTime= (new Date()).getTime(); //code execution start time

function createtrigger() {
var currTime = (new Date()).getTime(); //current time
Logger.log((currTime-startTime)) //show time difference between start time and current time

//check if difference between current time and start time is greater than 0 is greater than starttime
if (currTime-startTime > 0 ) {
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
        //check if trigger  function name is "createtrigger"
        if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "createtrigger") {
            console.log("Trigger already exists. Hence not created");
        }
        //if trigger  function name is not "createtrigger" then create the trigger
        else
        ScriptApp.newTrigger("createtrigger")
        .timeBased()
        .everyMinutes(1)
        .create();
        console.log("Trigger created");
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime= (new Date()).getTime(); //code execution start time

function createtrigger() {
var currTime = (new Date()).getTime(); //current time
Logger.log((currTime-startTime)) //show time difference between start time and current time

//check if difference between current time and start time is greater than 0 is greater than starttime
if (currTime-startTime > 0 ) {
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    Logger.log(triggers);
    if (triggers.length>0){
      for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
        //check if trigger  function name is "createtrigger"
        if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "createtrigger") {
            Logger.log("Trigger already exists. Hence not created");
            break;
        }
        //if trigger  function name  "createtrigger"  was not found then create the trigger
        if (i==triggers.length) {
          ScriptApp.newTrigger("createtrigger")
          .timeBased()
          .everyMinutes(1)
          .create();
          Logger.log("Trigger created");
        }
      } 

    } else {
          ScriptApp.newTrigger("createtrigger")
          .timeBased()
          .everyMinutes(1)
          .create();
          Logger.log("Trigger created first time");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: A propos... Fun fact: `Logger.log()` and `console.log()` are getting me different results: https://imgur.com/Qx8faxv.png

Comment: If your issue was solved, please accept the answer, to help others facing similar issue

Comment: The logic was not correct. I edited the solution